# How to show that $3(a^4+b^4)+2a^4b^4\leq8$ if $a^3+b^3=2$

Tags: inequality

It is given that a and b belong to non negative real numbers and $a^3+b^3=2$. Then prove that $3(a^4+b^4)+2a^4b^4\leq8$

Comment: I tried C.S, R.M.S-A.M,Chebyshev inequality to prove that didn't work.Tried

Comment: At last  i tried by substituting the value of a by b.But that also didn't work.

Comment: Seem to recall this from somewhere - did you check elsewhere on this site?

Comment: Last night one of friend gave me this.But i failed to do.No i didn't check yet.

Answer (score 4):

By some quick AM-GM we have the following:

1. $3=a^3+b^3+1 \ge 3ab \implies ab \le 1$.
2. Also $a^3+1+1 \ge 3a \implies 3a \le 4-b^3$ and similarly $3b \le 4-a^3$.

Now we have all the ingredients to do:
$$LHS = 3a (a^3)+3b (b^3)+2ab(ab)^3 \le (4-b^3)a^3+(4-a^3)b^3+ 2\cdot 1(ab)^3 = 4(a^3+b^3)=8$$

Comment: You're welcome - besides, as I mentioned, I seem to remember this from somewhere.

Comment: But last night I met it first time.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not a new solution but a comment with a graphical display)

It might be of interest to have an idea of the tightness of the condition. This can be put in evidence by displaying the graphical representation of

$$y=3((2 - b^3)^{4/3} + b^4) + 2(2 - b^3)^{4/3} b^4 - 8$$

obtained by plugging relationship $a=(2-b^3)^{1/3}$ into the difference between LHS and RHS of the constraint.

It appears that

- there is a case of equality $a=b=1$, but
- this constraint is far from being "hard" on the rest of the values in $[0,2^{1/3}]$.

[image]